# How to use SASS (not SCSS) in Vue Nuxt.js

Tags: webpack, sass, nuxt.js

I have just created the [standard tutorial nuxt.js app](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation#using-code-create-nuxt-app-code-)

Referencing a central `.scss`-File in `nuxt.config.js` is not a problem (a few simple styles contained show effect, so it truly is working).

```
...
css: ['~/assets/scss/main.scss'],
scss: {},
sass: {},
plugins: [],
...
```

Referencing a `main2.sass` file however...

```
css: ['~/assets/scss/main2.sass'],
```

...gets me trouble:

main2.sass

```
h1.title
    background: yellow
    color: white !important
```

> ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been
>   initialised using an options object that does not match the API
>   schema.
>    - options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'. These properties are valid:

**Worth noting:** I did not add a `indentedSyntax` property yet!

I *then* tried doing so, inside the `sass`-array, and also inside a nested inner `sassOptions`...

```
sass: {
    sassOptions: {
        indentedSyntax: true
    }
},
```

But all no luck. – Do I need to stuff that somehow into webpack options (within `nuxt.config.js`) for webpack (under nuxt's hood) to realize?

**full error message in console:**

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
- options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'. These properties are valid:
object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (/depot/sandbox/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:49:11)
    at Object.loader (/depot/sandbox/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:36:28)

@ ./assets/scss/main2.sass 4:14-225 14:3-18:5 15:22-233
@ ./.nuxt/App.js
@ ./.nuxt/index.js
@ ./.nuxt/client.js
@ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

### update

Also this (after some extensive github searching) syntax is not helping:

```
css: [
    '~/assets/scss/main.scss',
    { src: '~/assets/scss/main2.sass', lang: 'sass' }
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar issue rolling back my *sass-loader* package to version **7.0.0** vice version **8.0.0**.

Right now there is an open issue @vuejs/vue-cli in GitHub that should be related to this incompatibility:

[vue-cli and sass-loader@8 incompatibility #4513](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Sadly, rolling back is no option within the larger team. Perhaps the [currently last comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513#issuecomment-526921340) bears something, that helps. Let's see…

Answer (score 1):

"custom" fix for sass files

create index.scss in assets folder
in index.scss

```
@import "main.sass"
```

in nuxt.config.js

```
css: ['@/assets/sass/index.scss']
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked beautifly!

**nuxt.config.js** file:

```
 /* Global CSS */
  css: ['@/assets/main.sass'],
```

source: 
[Nuxt docs - Global Settings](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#global-settings)